# How can I use more than one table in SQLiteAssetHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using `SQLiteAssetHelper` dealing with database to realize selection, inserting and updating. But I need more than one `database`; can I put all the databases' method in one class? I tried, but the error is cannot find my second table. Thank you.

Comment: "But I need more than one database" -- why? A database can have multiple tables.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sorry for the confusion, I mean multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **all the databases method in one class**?

You can't have a single Helper class for multiple databases. Each database is represented by **one single** Helper. Then, you can create another class that takes an helper in its constructor and create methods using it.

**EDIT**

For each table you want to use, you need to create a class that extends `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Use a different name for each table in the DATABASE_NAME variable.

Then use the helper corresponding to the table you want to read or write to as normal. There is samples here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow

Comment: Then can I use more than one table?

Comment: Of course. Are you familiar with SQLiteOpenHelper before using SQLiteAssetHelper?

Comment: Not that.. I am completely new to java and sql. At first I use openHelper, but for using the database under asset, I change to SQLiteAssetHelper. I assign two table in the class, but in the main activity, the second table cannot be found. Is there any tutorial for the multiple tables?

Comment: "in the main activity, the second table cannot be found" -- presumably, your database does not have the second table. Bear in mind that if your app is already installed, simply running your app from an IDE (or the command line) will *not* replace your database, because it already exists, unless you are incrementing the schema version. You can uninstall the app, or use "Clear Data" in Settings, to get rid of the existing database and force the next run to unpack a fresh database from assets.

Comment: @CommonsWare is right too, or you can just increase the DATABASE_VERSION variable.

Comment: @bobby4078 I only create one class for the two tables, I will try two now. The two tables are totally different and they are both needed.